# ASP.NET and Posback?

Tags: c#, asp.net

When I use `checkbox` with a `postback`, my main class starts again at the first line. Therefore my variable changes again.

Like this:

```
public partial class Fırın1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    bool Checkboxlist1value, Checkboxlist1value = false;
    bool first_value=false;


    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        Panel1.Visible = false;
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            first_value = true;
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see in a small section of my code, when I click `checkbox` or `save` button class `fırın_1` starts again at the first line. Thus `first_value` changes to `false`. But I need `true` because the condition will change this value to true.

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks in advance for your cooperation.

Comment: Do you really need a postback on your checkbox?

Comment: Note: The value of `first_value` never changes to `false`. At the postback you get a new instance of the page class, so the variable `first_value` that you have in the postback is not the same variable that you assigned `true`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to persist values across a PostBack, you should generally store them in ViewState.

If I understand what you're trying to achieve, you should change `first_value` from a field to a property that's backed by ViewState.  For example (I've changed it from first_value to FirstValue in line with Microsoft guidelines):

```
public bool FirstValue
{
    get
    {
        object o = ViewState["FirstValue"];
        if (o == null) return false; // default is false
        return (bool) o;
    }
    set
    {
        ViewState["FirstValue"] = value;
    }
}

...

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{


    Panel1.Visible = false;
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        FirstValue = true;
    }
}
```